# SQL query filter, count if

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
user  |  app
name1   app1
name1   not an app
name1   app1
name1   app2
name2   not an app
name3   app1
name3   app3
name4   app1
name4   not an app2
name5   app1
name5   not an app
name5   not an app2
```

I need to get the cases where a user has an app1 and at least one type of app "not an app", which im going to call in this example not an app and not an app2.

I need to get back something like this:

```
user
name1
name4 
name5
```

Im trying to filter with WHERE AND NOT LIKE(s) then ORDER BY I think next step would be something like HAVING COUNT DISTINCT app = app1 > 2 but I get lost here where I have to start counting only if there is an app1...

Ideally id want also to know

```
user name: list of apps
user name1:  not an app, ...
user name4:  not an app2, ...
user name5:  not an app1, not an app2, ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is your real goal, because if you need *to get the cases where a user has an app1 and at least one "not an app"*

Your expected result

```
user
name1
name4 
name5
```

is wrong.

Check my fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbb566/7

```
SELECT `user`
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY `user`
HAVING SUM(IF(`app`='app1',1,0))>0
 AND SUM(IF(`app`='not an app',1,0))>0
```

**UPDATE** If you need any that starts with **'not an app'**

You can  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbb566/11 :

```
SELECT `user`
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY `user`
HAVING SUM(IF(`app`='app1',1,0))>0
 AND SUM(IF(`app` LIKE 'not an app%',1,0))>0
```

Comment: Is not, you are "filtering" not and app2 that's why is not counting it...
you should have in fiddle mysql something like `AND SUM(IF(`app`='not an app%',1,0))>0` but its not working either... fiddle might not be able to read it properly...

Comment: You didn't ask for *at least one starts with"not an app"*, you've asked for *at least one "not an app"*

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select user  from table
where app = 'app1' or app like 'not an app%'
group by user
having count(distinct app)>=2
```

Comment: Wouldn't the script return name3 too? Because it counts 'app1' >= 2.
While 'not an app' is a must condition.

Comment: My query looks like this not but it returning me an error I think to do with the query...
`$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT username, publishedapp
FROM tbl_name
WHERE publishedapp = \"Mencap@Work2-1\"
OR publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%Desktop%\"
AND publishedapp NOT LIKE \"%RDP%\"
ORDER BY username
HAVING COUNT(publishedapp) > 1";`

Comment: @maco1717 Why did you choose wrong answer? this query will return users with 2 records `app1` and no records `not an app1` for example. Is it what you were asking for? or even invers, when user has no `app1` records, but has 2 `not an app`

Answer (score 0):

This should work;  get to know the "like" operator and subqueries

```
select user, app
from tablename
where user in 
(select user
from tablename
where app = 'app1')
and app like '%not an app%'
order by user
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below: I hope it would give desired results over large data too

```
SELECT DISTINCT( T1.[User] )
FROM dbo.Temp T1
WHERE App = 'app1'
AND EXISTS ( SELECT [User] FROM dbo.Temp WHERE [User] = T1.[User] AND [App] LIKE '%not an app%' )
```